# Set default values in sparse nested map in clojure

Tags: clojure

I've got a set of default values for a map, and I'd like to be able to take any stored map that doesn't have the values and apply the defaults.

i.e. if I've got the following inputs

```
(def defaults {:config {:tablet {:urls [] :enable false}}})
(def stored   {:config {:tablet {         :enable true }}})
```

I'd like to be able to create the following result.

```
              {:config {:tablet {:urls [] :enable true}}}
```

So the stored values are used when they exist, but the defaults are used when that key doesn't exist.  I've tried `merge`, `merge-with merge`, `merge-with concat`, `merge-with conj`, and a few other incantations but none seem quite to work.  One that *does* work is, if you know the max depth of nesting, `(merge-with (partial merge-with ... (partial merge-with merge) ... ))` but that's pretty hacky.  Seems like there should be a simpler solution since this seems like it would be not-uncommon in Clojuresque code.

Comment: [deep-merge](https://github.com/richhickey/clojure-contrib/blob/2ede388a9267d175bfaa7781ee9d57532eb4f20f/src/main/clojure/clojure/contrib/map_utils.clj#L41)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along the lines of the following should let you merge arbitrarily deeply nested maps:

```
(defn deep-merge [& ms]
    (apply merge-with
           (fn [& vs]
             (if (every? map? vs)
               (apply deep-merge vs)
               (last vs)))
           ms))

(deep-merge {:config {:tablet {:urls [] :enable false}}}
            {:config {:tablet {         :enable true }}})
; => {:config {:tablet {:urls [], :enable true}}}
```